# Mega menu dropdown menu item shows on loading how to hide a dropdown menu item in magento 2

Tags: megamenu

Mega menu shows on loading in frontend  magento 2 i want to hide on loading

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305060 and add your menu id in css

Comment: no its not working @rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way...

```
<ul style="display:none"></ul>
```

Comment: i will  try and update you @rakesh

Comment: it hides a entire nav bar @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar i have updated my answer

Comment: i will check it and  tell u

Comment: your previous answer worked for me @rakesh

Comment: Updated in my answer so other user helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using CSS.  Add this in your custom CSS and this will hide the menu during onload event of the body:

```
ul.dropdown-menu.fullwidth.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all {
display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: i will try and update you @magefms

Comment: okay I hope it will work for you.